# MethodDelegation with Passing Object Array to Specific Parameters Using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

```
interface Foo{
    Object foo(Object... args);
}

static class FooAdapter{
    Object foo2(String msg, Integer age) {
        System.out.println(msg+"=>"+age);
        return age;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    FooAdapter adapter = new FooAdapter();
    Foo foo = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Foo.class)
            .method(ElementMatchers.named("foo"))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(adapter))
            .make()
            .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
            .getLoaded()
            .newInstance();
    foo.foo("hello", 10);
}
```

My Code is simple, I just want Delegate My Foo interface `foo` method call to `FooAdater` instance `foo2` method. But when i run test, ByteBuddy seems do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegation is succeeding because Byte Buddy decides that `Object::equals` is the best method that can be bound to your adapter. It cannot bind the `foo2` method, because it is expecting two arguments of type `String` and `Integer` while `foo` only declares `Object[]`.

The delegator you want to define is:

```
Object foo2(@Argument(0) Object[] arguments) {
  System.out.println(arguments[0] + "=>" + arguments[1]);
  return arguments[0];
}
```

where the argument is bound correctly. Otherwise, you might want to use the `MethodCall` instrumentation where you can explode the array arguments. You need to use dynamic typing in this case as there is no way to prove that `foo` is invoked with a string and an integer.

Comment: Thanks, I considered using bytebuddy instrumentation, but i found it quite hard for me to understand the abstraction of asm's. For example, i work it out with asm. Winterhalter would you give me some more doc about learning bytebuddy instrumentation?

Comment: You can start out with the documentation on bytebuddy.net. Beyond that there is a lot javadoc.